# Where is the output file of microsoft ILGenerator?

Tags: c#, il, ilgenerator

I've used Microsoft ILGenerator and its Emit member. I want to know where I can find the output il file which is generated by it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generated IL is not saved to disk automatically. You need to first ensure that your  AssemblyBuilder is created (through `AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly()`) with an AssemblyBuilderAccess of Save or RunAndSave.

Once you have generated all your IL, you can then use the `Save()` method on the AssemblyBuilder to save the generated assembly to disk.